# Codeigniter update 2 element data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

I have traveller data and I want to update all data in traveller. [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Asrd.png)

**I have controller code for update function like this**

```
function transaction_update(){
    $traveller  = $this->input->post('traveller');

    $data = array(
                  'traveller'=> array($traveller)
            );
    $update = $this->cms_model->update_transaction($data, $booking_id);
```

**And I have view code like this**

```
<td><input type="text" name="traveller" value="<?php echo $rr; ?>"></td>
```

When I use this code, it just edit test2 in traveller data. What I dont understand is how to edit both test1 and test2 in traveller data?

Comment: Can I see your model `update_transaction`?

Comment: function update_transaction($data, $booking_id){
  // print_r($booking_id);
  return $this->mongo_db->where(array('booking_id'=>$booking_id))
         ->set($data)
         ->update('tr_booking');
 } @Roshan

Comment: what is the value of `$booking_id` by the way? I think `$booking_id` is the id of `test2` **ONLY**

Comment: no. $booking_id is id both test1 and test2 @Roshan

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your insert statement on your controller. It should be like this,

```
function transaction_update(){
$traveller = $this->input->post('traveller');

$data = array(
    'traveller' =>  array($traveller)
);

 for($i =0;$i <= count($data); $i++){
        $update = $this->cms_model->update_transaction($data[$i]['traveller'], $booking_id);
    }
}
```

Also please elaborate more what is the output of `$booking_id`. Is that on `array` or `object`.

Comment: $booking_id is on object not in array.

Comment: it shows error : Update of data into MongoDB failed: localhost:27017: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead. For example: {$mod: {: ...}} not {$set: []}